# Install another Settings app?

Tags: settings, installation

Is it possible to install a different settings app than the one my phone came with?  Specifically, I'd like the official Google one.

Comment: Not sure about this, since Settings app is related to system configuration, and every vendor may modify it (i.e. the name of activity, key, etc) and it may not be compatible with other Settings app.

Comment: If you've got a Galaxy s4 then you could install the settings app of the Galaxy S5, however I don't think it's possible to install a google settings app on a Galaxy S4 because what @AndrewT. said. Please tell your device name.

Comment: The one your phone came with is the one that was designed to be used with the current ROM on your device. Look on XDA forums for root and a custom ROM (AOSP) for your device (since you don't mention what it is or Android version), you'll have the "Official Google" settings app then. Don't install another settings app from a different device, **you will corrupt you device** (possibly bootlooping or bricking it).

Comment: Agreed with above-- the settings app is tightly integrated with Android's framework.  You leave out a lot of information in your question-- your device, the version of Android, whether it is rooted or not, and what you're looking to get out of the new settings-- do you just want a different layout/presentation?  Or do you want actual features you've seen in other versions of Android?  When you say the "official Google one", do you mean Settings in stock Android?  The same or different version? FYI- Settings aren't part of the ["Google experience" apps](http://www.google.com/mobile/android/).

Comment: I currently am using Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini with default ROM, because I can't get flashing recovery to work.  I was hoping I could change settings, since it's pretty much the only difference now.

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative method here if what you're looking for is greater control and access to settings not available through the default settings UI: [Settings Database Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.setedit22&hl=en_US)

Word of warning: you can possibly brick your phone if you don't know what you're doing, so proceed with caution, back up your data, and thoroughly research any customization.

Through this app, you can directly access and modify the db values for your various device settings.  This doesn't necessarily require root (might depend on device model & OS version), as you can grant some of the permissions through an ADB command.

EDIT: fixed link.

Answer (score 0):

A Galaxy S3 is to highly customised by Samsung that you can't install a stock settings app. It will corrupt/brick your phone if you try so.

However you maybe could install the settings app of a galaxy s4 mini because it is almost the same. But I am not sure. **do it at your own risk**

Hope my answer helped.